# Can a batched BizTalk file have the filename set in orchestration?

Tags: biztalk

If I'm sending a single EDI file, then I can set the outbound filename in the orchestration by setting FILE.ReceivedFileName in a shape, and then using the %SourceFileName% macro when configuring the Send port. But what if I'm batching EDI files - is there a way to set the filename there as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a dynamic send with a `file://` URI, but your method could work, too.  Richard Seroter has a blog article covering both approaches here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richardbpi/archive/2006/07/05/656948.aspx